# Why two independent if-loops are always put in different always/process blocks?

Tags: vhdl, flipflop, process

```
architecture rtl of goodFFstyle is
signal q1 : std_logic;
begin
    process (clk)
    begin
       if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
          if (rst_n = '0') then
             q1 <= '0';
          else
             q1 <= d;
          end if;
      end if;
end process;

process (clk)
begin
   if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
      q2 <= q1;
   end if;
end process;
end rtl;
```

In the above example the second process could have avoided if q2 assigned is included in the first process.

```
architecture rtl of goodFFstyle is
    signal q1 : std_logic;
    begin
        process (clk)
        begin
           if (clk'event and clk = '1') then
              if (rst_n = '0') then
                 q1 <= '0';
              else
                 q1 <= d;
              end if;
              q2 <= q1;
          end if;
    end process;
```

Second example uses less lines of code, but most of them prefer first way of coding. So my doubt, is there is any advantage if we code in first method?

Comment: On a related note, the `if (clk'event and clk = '1') then` style is generally not encouraged, instead, use `if (rising_edge(clk)) then`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the second style unless it is taken to excess.

If the functionality of Q1 and Q2 are closely related, I would prefer the single process. Chasing intermediate signals between hundreds of tiny processes only obscures the design.

And I have never seen a synthesis tool that can't generate optimal hardware from it either.